# Windows 8 doesn't hibernate after dual-boot with Debian

Tags: windows, unix, shutdown, hibernate

I have recently installed Debian on my laptop and am now dual-booting it with Windows 8. Windows 8 shows following problems: after spending some time setting up Debian and booting up Win again, I noticed that no soft power off options worked on my Windows 8. By that I mean, I can not hibernate, sleep or shutdown. The GUI doesn't give any notification of failure. What happens is, screen goes blank (like it should), but doesn't power off; after moving the mouse, it lights back up, just to see that it's at the log on (technically unlock screen, because it doesn't log the user out).

When using `shutdown /h`, everything happens like explained above. After failed attempt to hibernate, I unlock the workstation and this is what the `cmd` console looks like:

> C:\Users\Domas>shutdown /h
>
> The requested system device cannot be found.(15299)
>
> C:\Users\Domas>

I have been googling for the past week or so to no avail. I ask your help in diagnosing the problem. What information could I provide?

Cheers, Dom

EDIT:

Additional notes:
Apparently, `shutdown /s /f` shuts down successfully. Though, same doesn't work for hibernation. And System Event Logs don't provide any info.

Comment: And this is happening regardless of how you end up Debian session? I mean even when you `halt` properly without hibernating.

Comment: Does 'shutdown /f /s /t 0' (without the single quotes) work? Are there any errors listed in the System Event log?

Comment: Yes, this happens regardless of whether I hibernate or shutdown in Debian.

Comment: Mark, System Event Logs show nothing. However, `shutdown /s /f` shuts down successfully. Hibernating with /h still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I use

> SysinternalsSuite\psshutdown.exe -h

run as Administrator.

psshutdown.exe is available here:

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools

> https://live.sysinternals.com

Answer (score -1):

Go to **Control panel** ->  **Power options**
Click on the **Choose what power buttons do** in the left side menu.
On the top of the window you should find an option -
 **Change settings that are currently unavailable**
click on that ,
scroll down and select Hibernate in shutdown settings.

This is what I did to re-enable hibernate on my machine , the old windows 7 tricks don't seem to work

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't help. This is a bit irrelevant as well. As far as I can tell, my problem is caused by installing Debian, due to caused reorganization on whatever level, Windows feels lost when a shutdown is requested. That's the 5 year old's version. I need help understanding what's actually happening.